# How do I implement a Singleton that returns an array of UIImages?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I want to create a Class called ImageStore, and when I call ImageStore.getStore() I want to receive an array of predefined UIImages. For example:

```
[UIImage(named: "pic1"), UIImage(named: "pic2"), UIImage(named: "pic3")]
```

I know the starting point is:

```
class ImageStore {

    static let getStore = ImageStore()

}
```

But how/where do I add the code that sets up the array of images?

Comment: You never subclass NSArray. Absolutely absolutely never.

Comment: @gnasher729 Understood. Do you then have a recommendation on what to do given the objective I have?

Comment: Make `ImageStore` contain the array instead of subclassing it.  The array can be a private var and all the operations would be done using `ImageStore.getStore...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ImageStore {
    static let images = [UIImage(named: "pic1"), UIImage(named: "pic2"), UIImage(named: "pic3")]
    private init() {} //disallow creation of objects
}
```

access with `ImageStore.images`